# 302 Redirect in AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a webstack that is currently serving both dynamic and static content. I want start serving the static content from AWS CloudFront without having to change all of the urls.

So I set up CloudFront to serve the static content from AWS S3 and the dynamic content from a custom url (current webstack). This worked however CloudFront was making the request to our webstack via a rewrite rule.

Is it possible for CloudFront to return a `302 redirect` so that the request to my webstack would come from the users browser?

Unfortunately this is critical for our application to work properly.

Comment: *return a 302 redirect so that the request would come from the users browser?* The request is already "coming  from" the user's browser.  Can you clarify the actual problem you're trying to solve?   What specifically is broken?

Comment: The request to the webstack, i need cloudfront to return a 302 so the the user will directly hit webstack. I could only get cloudfront to make the request to the webstack.

Comment: Okay, but **why**?  It should work through CloudFront if CloudFront is configured correctly.  Many things, like most request headers, cookies, and query strings, are not forwarded by CloudFront by default, but can be enabled... which is why I ask, what is the specific thing that isn't working?

Comment: Its actually a header that gets injected by an ISP to all http requests on their network to whitelisted hosts (IP + domain). If the user gets the content from cloudfront we don't have any control of the IP address that the user is hitting.

Comment: What is your thoughts? I am thinking that it is not possible to achieve what I want. We may need to consider another option.

Comment: A header that gets injected by an ISP?  A request header, a response header? What is its purpose, and for whose benefit?  Not sure why you aren't using HTTPS, for that matter.  Yes, if there are specific paths that you want to redirect to a different hostname, it is possible to configure S3 to return the redirect, which CloudFront will then cache and return.  Is it a single path, a ditectory, or what?

Comment: IMO, its not possible to create a 302 redirection only using Cloudfront.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible, because CloudFront should follow 302 redirects and cache the result, rather than return the 302 redirect to the client.